# scaling and cutting a portion of video using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to upload a video that is 640 x 480. Using FFmpeg I am trying to resize to a square but I am having much difficulty.

if i use s=320x320  in my command or scale 320x320

```
    ->setVideoScale(320, 320)
```

the image is distored.

If i change the aspect ratio 1:1 i get black bars.

is there a way to actually just cut a RECT in the video. IE i want to be able to re save the video and it only capture

```
   x 0 to 320
   y 0 to 320
```

or whatever bounds I pick.

Basically I do not want to re-size I just want to be able to re record a certain portion of the video. is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want to `crop`: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-19

Comment: Sounds like you want to add that as an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out FFMPEG's [video filters](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop). There is a crop option that will do what you're asking for, specifically the first example.

Depending on the library you're using to interface with FFMPEG, something like the following might work per your example:

```
->addCommand('-vf', 'crop=320:320:0:0');
```